# check is SSH prompt for password or not

Tags: bash, ssh, passwords

Hi I have a list of few hundred hosts. I want to run a command using  ssh in a loop,  if my ssh keys are set properly, then I execute a command if I get challenge for password  I want to skip to the next host

So lets say I have hosta and hostb and hostc.  I can do a ssh to hosta & hostc , but hostb is challenging me for password. Is there a way to check if a hosts will challenge me for password or not?  So my logic would be

```
if I get challenge from $host; then
   skip host 
else
   ssh $host 'command'
fi
```

I hope this makes sense. Thanking you in advance

Comment: Check this: https://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/

Answer (score 7):

```
for host in host1 host2 host3; do
    ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no $host command
done
```

To make it parallel add `&`:

```
for host in host1 host2 host3; do
    ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no $host command &
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a thing you do regularly, I would suggest looking at dsh.
http://www.tecmint.com/using-dsh-distributed-shell-to-run-linux-commands-across-multiple-machines/

it allows you to make a list of your servers, and run commands against ALL of them, or just subsets(web, db, app, etc)

you can create global files, or create your own personal files.

Answer (score 1):

`ssh` has an option, called `BatchMode`.

You can use it like

```
ssh -o BatchMode ...
```

and it won't ask you anything, but skip the connection attempt.

Comment: yeah, but then it runs sequentially. this is the worst scenario

Answer (score -1):

Or use rundeck - this can be found at http://rundeck.org