# Security Audit: How to check if ssh server asks for a password

Tags: security, ssh

Let's assume that I `grep /etc/ssh/sshd_config '^PasswordAuthentication no$'` and get a favorable result.

How can I check that the running server is, in fact, using that configuration presently (i.e. it has been restarted since the change)?

I'm looking for an empirical way to get a clear "yes, this ssh server will accept passwords" or a clear "no, passwords are not allowed on this server" by using the ssh client in a scriptable way.

Obviously I can manually run `ssh $USER@$HOST -i /path/to/badkey` and wait and see if I get a password prompt, but that would not be scriptable (and even if it were, it would always exit with an error status).

This is not a duplicate of [check is SSH prompt for password or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081581/check-is-ssh-prompt-for-password-or-not) because the use case given lead to answers for a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run this:

```
 ssh -v -o Batchmode=yes  nosuchuser@theHost
```

Then look for this line in the verbose output:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

This lists the authentication methods which the server is prepared to accept. The value "password" indicates that the user can authenticate by providing a password. "keyboard-interactive" is similar, except that the server can provide a custom prompt. For more details, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/894625/54530).

Comment: I meant to post this on serverfault, not stackoverflow. Oops. (I wonder if I can move it) Thanks for the answer!